# SQL - Customers with no payment

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for SQL code for the following:

Display the order IDs for customers who have not made any payment, yet, on that order.

Note:  There is a customer, order and payment table.  The customerID is not in the payment table.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why can't you do it yourself? A specific problem? Error with your current query?

Comment: How far have you gotten?  `SELECT o.orderID FROM orders o` ?

Comment: I'm very new to SQL so I am pretty much lost.  I'll put something in here if you need me to, but it may not be right.

Comment: I'm a student who is not a CS major...just trying to learn for my dads business.

Comment: Customer_t has CustomerID, CustomerName - Order_t has OrderID, CustomerID - Payment_t has PaymentID, OrderID, and PaymentDate

Answer (score 0):

you haven't given much to go on.

```
select id 
  from orders o
    left join payments p
      on p.order_id = o.id
  where p.order_id is null
```

assuming i have the relations right, this will give you all orders that have had no payments made against them.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use an **anti-join** pattern, e.g.

```
SELECT o.orderID
  FROM orders o
  LEFT
  JOIN payments p
    ON p.orderID = o.orderID
 WHERE p.orderID IS NULL
```

That says get all the rows from `orders`, along with matching `payments`. If there are `orders` for which there are no matching `payments`, then the row from `orders` will be returned along with `NULL` values in place of the "missing" row from `payments`. (The keyword **`LEFT`** preceding the keyword **`JOIN`** tells MySQL to do an "outer join", returning ALL rows from the table on the left side (that otherwise satisfy the predicates), even when there is no matching row from the table on the right side.)

The "trick" is the predicate in the WHERE clause, where we discard any rows from `orders` that had a matching row in `payments`, leaving us with `orders` that don't have any matching `payments`.

There are other query patterns that will achieve the same result, e.g. `NOT IN (subquery)`, `NOT EXIST (correlated subquery)`

For example:

```
 SELECT o.orderID
   FROM orders o
  WHERE o.orderID NOT IN 
        ( SELECT p.orderID  
            FROM payments p
           WHERE p.orderID IS NOT NULL
        )
```

-or-

```
 SELECT o.orderID
   FROM orders o
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM payments p
           WHERE p.orderID = o.orderID
        )
```

Comment: I will do it up real quick and post what I have in comments, thanks so much!

Comment: Again, thank you for your really quick response and actually teaching me something!  This is what I got...   `SELECT Order_t.OrderID 
FROM Orders_t
LEFT JOIN  Payments_t ON Payment_t.OrderID = Order.OrderID
WHERE Payment_t.OrderID IS NULL`